# Access require message

Tags: web3js, javascript, require, assert

I am using JavaScript to run some tests on my solidity contract. Since solidity ^0.4.22 you can have a message in require such as:

```
function Hello {
    require(msg.sender == 0x001234, "msg.sender MUST BE 0x001234"); 
}
```

When writing tests in javascript I can use the contractName.methods.function to access functions from within the solidity contract. Any idea how I could access the message from require or to implement to test that this message is shown correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this helper a little bit to check `error.message` should contain your message on the require

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/helpers/assertRevert.js

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found another possibility, basically using a try/catch and identify the error. Now I am going to integrate the message as well :D